# Why does the Tensor's value change?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

```
# Using Python state
x = tf.zeros([10, 10])
x += 2  # This is equivalent to x = x + 2, which does not mutate the original
        # value of x
print(x)
```

x changed from 0 to 2. 
It shows the following result of x = tf.zeros([10,10]):

```
<tf.Tensor: id=266, shape=(10, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Then it changed to the following after executing: x += 2

```
<tf.Tensor: id=263, shape=(10, 10), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Why does the comment say "which does not mutate the original value of x"?

Comment: Note that the ID is different. You got a new object; the original object is intact with zeroes. A new object is created, and the object that `x` points to is updated to the new object, rather than mutating the existing object.

Comment: When x += 2, and a new ID is created for x, we lost the handle to the original 'x', which is equivalent to a change in the original x. Isn't it? How can we access the original 'x' if needed, in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Heald is right. It's eaiest to see the difference using NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(2)
b = a  # Set up an alias

a += 1  # NumPy operations are in-place - they mutate the array
print(b)  # Output: 3!
```

Since the `ndarray`'s `__iadd__` mutates the array in-place, any references to the array will update, so the code prints `3`. NumPy arrays are more like objects in this regard.

Compare this with TF `Tensor`s, which are immutable (code is TF 2):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(2)
b = a  # Set up an alias

a += 1  # Tensor operations are not in-place - a new tensor is created
print(b)  # Output: 2
```

That prints 2, because `Tensor` is immutable. So they are more like primitive values.

Accessing the original value is then straightforward - just assign it to some other variable (like I did with `b = a`).

Another way to describe this is using lists:

```
l = [1]
l[0] = 2  # I can mutate the list...
l = [2]   # ... or I can create a new one
```

Comment: The key is to store the original value somewhere.